# Nuxt3: Load global data from API / CMS, make it available to all components (layout, pages,..) and refetch on action

Tags: nuxt.js, state, global, nuxtjs3, storyblok

I have written a small website with Nuxt 3 and tried to load data (like global settings and/or labels) from Storyblok that are language specific. I do this within the `app.vue` and that works fine for loading the data initially.

Also the project has a default layout which contains a header component that has a language switch, which on change should (re-)fetch global settings and labels for the new locale.

See the code for reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-mukfwr?file=app.vue

Is there a better way to achieve loading global data which fetch can be triggerd from any component? It does not really feel like the way to go. Loading the story on app and page level does not feel right. Also when I use `useAsyncStoryblok` to load the global settings instead of `useFetch` I get following Vue Warning:

[image]